# Accessing array values show undefined

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
var data = [{"fname":"john","sname":"doe","id":"2"},{"country":"England"}];
```

I tried iterating with this:

```
var comment='';

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    comment = data[i];

}
```

I access the data with this:

```
alert(comment.fname);
alert(comment.sname);
alert(comment.id);
alert(comment.country);
```

Only `comment.country` displays correctly, the rest show `undefined`.

Comment: You need to call `$.parseJSON()` to convert the string to an array.

Comment: After you fix that, you have another problem. At the end of the loop, `comment` will just contain the last element of the array. That element only has `country`, not `fname`, `sname`, or `id`.

Comment: It is data sent from the server side via ajax

Comment: Did you use `dataType: 'json'` in the AJAX call, so that it would be parsed automatically? Why are you showing it as a string if it has already been parsed?

Comment: yes, i did that already. It just can't access the other data apart from country. Been battling with this for hours already.

Comment: then the only problem is what I wrote about the loop. What are you trying to accomplish by overwriting `comment` each time through the loop? Why are the two items in the array so different, arrays should usually be used for uniform data.

Comment: I added an element to the initial array at the server side `$user[]=array('country'=>'England');`. That's the only way i could fetch all the data that is needed

Comment: Ok, your actual problem is that you're mangling the data on the server side with that. Instead you should probably do `$user[0]['country'] = 'England';`.

Comment: Or if you're returning multiple users, it should be `$user[$i]['country'] = 'England';`

Comment: `$user[0]['country'] = 'England';` this gave me an error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`. I am using Laravel for the server side.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data ='[{"fname":"john","sname":"doe","id":"2"},{"country":"England"}]';
```

This array holds 2 different objects. If the same object has fname, sname, id and country, you should probably make them one.

```
var data ='[{"fname":"john","sname":"doe","id":"2","country":"England"}]';
```

Comment: It's not an array, it's a string.

Comment: I am assuming that he parses the string before iterating through it. I am aware that var foo = "a_string" is a string.

Comment: You're right. He says he gets a correct result for `comment.country`, so it must be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is overwriting `comment` each time through the loop, so at the end it just contains the last element of `data`. If you want `comment` to contain properties from the other elements, you need to pick them up during the loop.

```
comment = {}
$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
    $.extend(comment, obj); // Merge the properties if each element into comment
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got it;

I did not change the codes at the server side.

```
var comment=[];
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $.each(val, function(index, value){
            comment[index]=value;
    });
});
```

And all the values where displayed

```
alert(comment.fname);
alert(comment.sname);
alert(comment.id);
alert(comment.country);
```